# How to close the modal in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am newbie to react native developing. I want to close the modal component on pressing outside the modal in reactnative. Below is my code.

```
state = {
    visibleModal : false,
};

_hideModal(){
  this.setState({
    visibleModal: true,
  })
}


render(){
    return(
        <View style={
            [styles.container,
                {backgroundColor: this.state.visibleModal ? 'rgba(47, 60, 73, 0.75)': 'white'}
            ]}>

            <Text>Text Behind Modal</Text>

            { this._renderButton('BUTTON', () => this.setState({ visibleModal: true}) ) }
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {this._hideModal()}}>
            <Modal animationType={"slide"}
                   transparent={true}
                   visible={this.state.visibleModal}>

                      <View style={styles.modalContent}>
                          <Row />
                      </View>

            </Modal>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just add this prop in Modal

```
onRequestClose={() => { this.visibleModal(false); } }
```

It will close your modal on pressing back button

```
<Modal animationType={"slide"}
   transparent={true}
   visible={this.state.visibleModal}
   onRequestClose={() => { this.visibleModal(false); } }
>
```

**EDIT**

Above code will work only on Android as per the [document](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.46/docs/modal.html#onrequestclose).

For both,

You can add custom button to close modal

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
        this.setState({visibleModal: false})
    } }>
    <Image
        style={[styles.modalBackIcon]}
        source={require('../../theme/images/back-icon.png')} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: You haven't specified that ;)

Comment: Should i enclose the touchableopacity inside or outside the modal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149786/discussion-between-hash-and-jigar-shah).

Comment: the OP asked how to close the modal by clicking on the background. You haven't answered his question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Modal animationType={"slide"}
           transparent={true}
           visible={this.state.visibleModal}>
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {this.close_modal()}}>
                 <View style={styles.modalContent}>
                     ....
                 </View>
             </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </Modal>
```

this is sample of my code when you tap outside to close your modal

than so **close_modal** function **visibleModal** get false value

for exp.

```
this.setState({ visibleModal: false });
```

Answer (score -1):

Question :

To close modal when clicking outside the modal.

Solution:

Just remove function call on TouchableWithoutFeedback,it will work..

```
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {}}>
  <Modal animationType={"slide"}
               transparent={true}
               visible={this.state.visibleModal}>

                  <View style={styles.modalContent}>
                      <Row />
                  </View>
        </Modal>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```